# Creating JPanels with a titled border in a for loop from user input

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, jpanel, titled-border

I want to create a for loop that creates `JPanel` containers with titled headers. the number of iterations depends on the user input from previous interfaces.

```
int noofpara=Integer.parseInt(data[6]);

for(int i=1;i<=noofpara;i++){
    jPanel1.add(new JPanel().setBorder(new TitledBorder("Perimeter"+i)));       
}
```

The `noofpara` is the number of perimeters the user chose according to that the for loop should create panels with the titled border with the number of perimeters. the error appears at the `jpanel1.add...` where it says void type not allowed.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Always copy/paste error and exception output!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make new panel and add.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= noofpara; i++) {
    JPanel innerPane = new JPanel();
    innerPane.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Perimeter" + i));
    jPanel1.add(innerPane);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,  the error no longer shows up put the panels won't apper in the interface.

Answer (score 1):

`JPanel#setBorder` method has `void` return type, which mean it doesn't return any value when that method invoked.

But `JPanel#add` method need a value in order to invoked, it gives compilation error since setBorder is void.

You can simply fix this by this.

```
JPanel childPanel = new JPanel();
childPanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Perimeter" + i));
jPanel1.add(childPanel);
```

Comment: To be precise [JPanel.add](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add(java.awt.Component)) expects a `Component` argument.  +1